# Youtube embed iframe, using Chrome I get a black box

Tags: html, youtube, embed, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I want to embed a youtube video in a bootstrap [one page scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) web page, exactly in a [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) video slider.
I have a problem with both Chrome and Firefox (no problem using Safari).
Here is my code:

```
   <section class="videos">
    <div class="container">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="top:125%">
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" style="top:100px;">
              <div class="item active">
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                  <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/XXXX?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                  <iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/XXXX?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

I get two error:

- In my console I get:

  ```
  Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.domain.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
  Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
  ```
- The videos, appears as black boxes.

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you using an  object for the videos you want to embed in your site instead of the iframe. It has a better web browser independent behaviour and works as well with other video providers that enable sharing (dailymotion, vimeo)

```
<embed width="756" height="461" style="display: block;" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/nlcIKh6sBtc?autohide=1&version=3?autohide=1&version=3&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#000000" scale="scale" allowfullscreen="true" salign="tl" allowscriptaccess="never" wmode="opaque">
```

The above code snippet is an example of how to share a youtube video on a web page with various parameters. Hope this helped.